# why my class code do not activate then def in class make some change in instance?

Tags: python

`def apply_raise` doesn't activate.. why? pls help me

```
class Employee():
    raise_amount = 1.1
    raise_percentage = 10
    def __init__(self,name,education,age,wage):
        self.name = name
        self.education = education
        self.age = age
        self.wage = wage
    def __str__(self):
        return "안녕하세요.저는 %s 입니다. 저의 학력은 %s 입니다." %(self.name, self.education)

    def apply_raise(self,raise_percentage,wage):
        print('%d%% 인상되어 연봉은 %s입니다.'%(self.raise_percentage, self.wage))
        self.wage = int(self.wage * self.raise_amount)
        self.raise_percentage = (self.raise_amount-1)*100
        return

taedragon = Employee('Taedragon', '로스쿨졸업', 31, '20000')
taedragon.apply_raise(10, 22000)
```

Error:

```
self.wage = int(self.wage * self.raise_amount)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: I believe if you look at how you are initialising the object: `Employee('Taedragon', '로스쿨졸업', 31, '20000')` you have a string for `wage` instead of a numeric type. So try:  `Employee('Taedragon', '로스쿨졸업', 31, 20000)`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this line:

```
taedragon = Employee('Taedragon', '로스쿨졸업', 31, '20000')
```

You are passing `wage='20000'`, which is a *string*. You cannot multiply strings with floats.

Do this instead:

```
taedragon = Employee('Taedragon', '로스쿨졸업', 31, 20000)
```

Answer (score 1):

While instantiating `Employee`, your last argument should be `20000` instead of `'20000'`

(You must pass a numeric type rather than a string type)